# Use true Solarized colors from within tmux in iTerm2

Tags: tmux, iterm2, plugin-solarized

How can I use vim (8.2) within a tmux session in iTerm2, with Solarized colors? I have the Solarized colors set with my terminal, as [suggested in the docs for vim solarized colors plugin](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users). When I call Vim from within a tmux session, the colors are clearly different, as below - in particular there's a jarring change in the background color in some places. How can I specify that the appearance is the same, regardless of whether I'm running from within a tmux session?

Note that I do not want to use a 256 color palette.

**Normal vim session**

[image: normal]

**When running from within tmux**

[image: tmux]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
set -ag terminal-overrides ',*:RGB'
# for older tmux
# set -ag terminal-overrides ',*:Tc'
```

Might be interesting:

- https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/622
- https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/34

Comment: This seems to work. A note to any other newcomers to tmux (from screen). Your settings will  not be reloaded from `~/.tmux.conf` if you have any other currently running sessions.